# how to use result of collect_set in hive udf - evaluate method?

Tags: hadoop, hive, udf

**Hive query -**

```
select ...MYUDF(collect_set(col1))..from tableN
```

Here col1 is of the type string. I want to perform certain logic on this passed collect_set of data.
For user defined function I am extending class **UDF** and using the evaluate method. What should be the **signature of evaluate method** as array is getting passed from hive. I want to return string array from UDF.

```
public **<returnType>** evaluate(**<collect as what>**)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayList<Text>`  (`import java.util.ArrayList`)